# Pre-compiling LINQ queries when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to pre-compile queries in my Entity Framework application using my entities object.

I receive an error stating that There is no implicit reference conversion from **myEntities** to **System.Data.Linq.DataContext**.

An example of my compiled query is below. myEntities inherits 'ObjectContext', which is probably the root of the problem but I'm not sure why.

```
    //Compiled Version
    public static Func<myEntities, Users_GetUsersInRoleInputs, IQueryable<UserRole>> FilteredResult =

               CompiledQuery.Compile<myEntities, Users_GetUsersInRoleInputs, IQueryable<UserRole>>(

               (myEntities, Users_GetUsersInRoleInputs criteria) =>
                   (from t1 in dc.UserRoles
                   where (t1.Role_ID == criteria.RoleId)
                   select t1));

    public class Users_GetUsersInRoleInputs
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    }
```

Could anybody suggest why this might be and how I can use query compilation in my project?

Comment: myEntities inherits ObjectContext - sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: so it is a class? not an instantiated class?

Comment: It's a partial class and contained within the designer of my EDMX file

Comment: Shouldn't `(myEntities, Users_GetUsersInRoleInputs criteria)` be `(myEntities dc, Users_GetUsersInRoleInputs criteria)`?

Comment: what is `dc` ? Any why is myEntities a class name **and** a parameter name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong `CompiledQuery`. There is [one for L2S](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.compiledquery.aspx) and [another for L2E](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.compiledquery.aspx). It's the latter you want. Check your `using` statement at the top of the file.

Comment: This led to the resolution of my problem. Thanks.